# How would I have the ability for users to upload video in HTML5, then send that to a Node.js server for it to be played back on a client?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-development-server

I want to know how I would be able to upload a MP4 from a user client, then send a request to the server to upload that, then eventually send it back to the client so it can be played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) package seems to be popular for uploading files to Node.js backends. Then you will have to store the file. Then you will need to have some scripting in place to accept input from the user (browser) specifying what file(s) they want to download.

So, It's several steps or tasks to complete your goal. Various methods available to get it done. For example, how to you wish to store user uploaded files? Cloud based storage, or the Node filesystem?